Add CSS class to media documents
In my creditor5.yml file I have added some styles
button:
      - name: 'primary'
        title: 'Primary link'
        attributeName: 'class'
        attributeValue: 'editor-btn--primary'
        modelElements: [ 'drupalMedia' ]
      - name: 'secondary'
        title: 'Secondary link'
        attributeName: 'class'
        attributeValue: 'editor-btn--secondary'
        modelElements: [ 'drupalMedia' ]
      - name: 'teaser'
        title: 'Teaser text'
        attributeValue: 'teaser-text'
        modelElements: [ 'drupalMedia' ]

These appear when I add a media item in my Editor.
How can I add these CSS classes to my documents?
function feature_site_preprocess_media(array &$variables): void {
  $dataAttribute = 'class';
  $attributeVal = $variables['attributes'][$dataAttribute] ?? FALSE;
}


For those who have the same problem. I have fixed it in another way.
I have added 3 display modes for my media type. Hereby I made 3 different templates for the display modes.
Editors can choose which display mode they want in the editor.
